# Subgroups of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$ isomorphic to $\Bbb R$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Is this the only subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$ isomorphic to $\Bbb R$?
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&a \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix} : a \in \Bbb R\right\}
$$
If not, can we describe all such subgroups?

(motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641721/bbb-r-is-homomorphic-image-of-gl-2-bbb-r))

Comment: Hint: Conjugation.

Comment: Up to conjugation, they are all upper triangular, not necessarily strictly.

Comment: You should clarify if you want these subgroups to be isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$ as topological groups (with subspace topology) or as abstract groups. The answers are different since there are many more subgroups isomorphic to  ${\mathbb R}$ as abstract groups.

Answer (score 5):

Well, at the very least there is
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ a&1\end{bmatrix} : a \in \Bbb R\right\}
$$

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the question is: Find all subgroup of $GL(2)$.

Comment: What about $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1+a^2&0 \\ a&2+a^2\end{bmatrix} : a \in \Bbb R\right\}$?

Comment: Also $$\left\{\pmatrix{a&0\\0&1}:a>0\right\}?$$

Comment: Those are all also valid suggestions.